# How to rewrite code that navigates node list

Tags: c#, refactoring

I have just written some code, which as i was writing i thought, this is going to be a nice generic method for searching for a particular node. When i finished i actually realised it was a mess :D

```
public String sqlReading(String fileName, String path, String nodeId )
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(fileName);

    XmlNodeList names = doc.SelectNodes(path);
    foreach (XmlNode xmlDocSearchTerm in names)
    {
        //if the attribute of the node i start at is the same as where i am now
        if (xmlDocSearchTerm.Attributes.Item(0).Value.ToString().Equals(nodeId))
        {
            //get a list of all of its child nodes
            XmlNodeList childNodes = xmlDocSearchTerm.ChildNodes;

            foreach (XmlNode node in childNodes)
            {
                //if there is a node in here called gui display, go inside
                if (node.Name.Equals("GUIDisplay"))
                {
                    XmlNodeList list = node.ChildNodes;
                    //find the sqlsearchstring tag inside of here
                    foreach (XmlNode finalNode in list)
                    {
                        if (finalNode.Name.Equals("sqlSearchString"))
                        {
                            return node.InnerText;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

What i intended to do was based on a path - i would start and check to see if the element had the id i was looking for, if it did then i wanted to get inside there and not stop going until i got to the sqlsearchstring tag which was buried two levels deeper. I have managed that, but the issue here is that now i seem to have almost hardcoded a path to the tag opposed to looping there. How could i change my code to stop me from doing this?

Its from the second foreach where its going wrong imo.

Thanks

Comment: With XPath, I think you can replace all the `foreach` loops with a single line of code.

Comment: Are you looking for XPath? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308333

Comment: LOL...  3 comments that reference XPath, within 30 seconds...  This XPath thing must be a fad ;-)   Some kind of new buzz word ;-)

Comment: ok i think xpath is the way to go lol! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested it but I believe something like this would work, by using a xpath. However I'm not sure the name of the attribute, or is it always the first attribute?

```
public String sqlReading(String fileName, String path, String nodeId)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(fileName);

    XmlNode foundNode = doc.SelectNodes(path).SelectSingleNode("*[@id='" + nodeId + "']/GUIDisplay/sqlSearchString");
    if (foundNode != null)
        return foundNode.InnerText;
    return string.Empty;

}
```

Comment: That should work if the name of targeted attribute is known (or also if we target _any_ attribute, using `"*[@*='"`... ).  However if the requirement is effectively to select the nodes which very first attribute has a value of `nodeId` irrespective of its name, one needs to express this predicate _outside_ of XPath, either in C#  (akin to foreach loop of OP) or in LINQ (akin to Dean Chalk's answer).  In other words, while XPath offers predicates based on the position of a _Node_ [within its siblings], I don't believe there is a way to specify the position of an attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if this is exaclty right (as I dont have an XML document to try it with, but something similar should work

```
var innerTexts = XDocument.Load(fileName)
    .Elements(path)
    .Where(n => n.Attributes().ElementAt(0).Value == nodeId)
    .SelectMany(n => n.Elements())
    .Where(n => n.Name == "GUIDisplay")
    .SelectMany(n => n.Elements())
    .Where(n => n.Name == "sqlSearchString")
    .Select(n => n.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say recursion is a safe bet (for iterating through nested child nodes) Though, from what I gather, the structure remains the same. And with that in mind, why not use `[XmlDocumentObj].SelectSingleNode("/[nodeId='"+nodeId+"']")` (or some facsimile) instead? This has the ability to search by attribute name, unless the XML structure is always changed and you never have constant tag (in which case XPath is probably a good idea).